# How to call cell in helper in cakephp 3?

Tags: cell, helper, cakephp-3.0

I need to call cell methods in my helper. I try this in my helper.

```
$cell = $this->cell('Inbox::expanded');
```

But it does not work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. The first one is to use the view instance inside the helper to render the cell:

```
$cell = $this->_View->cell('Inbox::expanded');
```

The other way is to add the `CellTrait` to your helper:

```
class MyHelper extends Helper {
    use Cake\View\CellTrait;

    public function aMethod() {
        $cell = $this->cell('Inbox::expanded');
    }
}
```